# Free Flex IDE's

Tags: apache-flex, ide, flex4, flexbuilder

could you recommend some good alternative Flex IDE? I am interested in free editions mostly but I will also take under consideration the paid ones.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should give a try to FlashDevelop and FDT.

FlashDevelop is free.

http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/
http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page

Rob

Comment: can you give the link for download flash builder for students?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't many things Adobe gives away for free :( You can try the trial version through Adobe CC, just Google it.

Answer (score 11):

FlashDevelop is free, however I'm not a fan of their Flex support.  It's better for straight actionscript development.  There's also the following IDEs:

- [FDT](http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/)
- [Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashbuilder/)
- [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)
- [Tofino for Visual Studio](http://www.ensemble.com/products/tofino.shtml)

Tofino is free, but you need Visual Studio which isn't free.  Flash Builder isn't free, but has a 60 day trial and if you're [unemployed or a student, you can get a free copy](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/flex/free/). IntelliJ has a 'community' edition which is free, but I'm not sure if it includes Flex in it.  Worth a try.  FDT is not free, but has a 30 day trial and if you're an open source project, will provide a free license for it.

I think that's it.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Great answer.  To clarify - IntelliJ does not support Flex in the free community edition, you have to purchase a full copy.  (Which is still cheaper than Flash Builder)

Comment: I just chatted with Adobe and there is no free version of FlashBuilder available. Neither for educational use nor for unemployed developers. I think they changed their policy again.
My recommendation is FDT (from powerflasher). There is a free (like free beer) version and their pricing for payed version is far more reasonable than Adobes.