# android development with flex 4.5 but free

Tags: android, apache-flex, flex4

Hi I've a pc (windows 7) and I'd like to use flex 4.5 sdk for developing android and ios app (future), but I like to do it with free tools.

I'm a bit confused about best enviroment and for difference between paid version of flex and no paid version,

There's also good library like as3isolib  is compatible with open sdk of flex?

Can also give me some tools like good ide, and which and where can download the right sdk from adobe site?

And the difference of speed for a app made in flex or in java in a 1ghz hi res (800x480) phone like nexus one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [J_A_X's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418058/free-flex-ides/5421331#5421331) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418058/free-flex-ides):

> FlashDevelop is free, however I'm not
>   a fan of their Flex support.  It's
>   better for straight actionscript
>   development.  There's also the
>   following IDEs:
>
> - [FDT](http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/)
> - [Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashbuilder/)
> - [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)
> - [Tofino for Visual Studio](http://www.ensemble.com/products/tofino.shtml)
>
> Tofino is free, but you need Visual
>   Studio which isn't free.  Flash
>   Builder isn't free, but has a 60 day
>   trial and if you're [unemployed or a
>   student, you can get a free copy](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/flex/free/).
>   IntelliJ has a 'community' edition
>   which is free, but I'm not sure if it
>   includes Flex in it.  Worth a try. 
>   FDT is not free, but has a 30 day
>   trial and if you're an open source
>   project, will provide a free license
>   for it.
>
> I think that's it.  Hope that helps.

As for libraries like as3isolib, while I haven't used it personally I would assume it would work without any issues. I've used other libraries like flexlib and the Flex 4 SDK with no troubles.