# difference between external and internal scripting of flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Actionscript in flash is applied in two ways first way is inside the Flash and second is the actionscript file is outside the fla file. So what is the difference between these two ways of scripting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash used to be a animation program more than a programming one. It still caries this background. You can code directly in the Flash timeline, even on different frames.
But I wouldn't recommend it.
This might be slightly difficult for little programs, and nearly impossible for big ones.

You are much better of with some external editor ([Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html), [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) (i use this one), [look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418058/free-flex-ides)).

And I recommend going for OOP over Procedural if you know how to.